# If line contains the letter r followed by a digit

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I have a list:

```
rconr01
scordr100
dcver101
ccpcr01
yccr10
scpor01
```

How would I add a dash `-` in front of the `r` that follows a number?
To get the following list:

```
rcon-r01
scord-r100
dcve-r101
ccpc-r01
ycc-r10
scpo-r01
```

`sed`, `awk` or `perl`.  I have no idea where to start.

I have tried `^[r][09]$` but this is over my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
 sed 's/r[0-9]/-&/' file
```

Answer (score 3):

As a Perl substitution:

```
s/(?=r\d)/-/
```

usable like `perl -pe's/(?=r\d)/-/' <file`

The `(?=...)` group is a *lookahead*, it matches when the following characters match the pattern, but it doesn't advance the position. Our pattern doesn't match a character, but it matches the position before the `r`. The minus is then substituted at this position..